# Ruby: how to make zero a number again? The .include? method seems to act weird

Tags: arrays, ruby, zero

```
  if arr.include?(0)
    puts "Please, try again. You cannot use zero!"
  end
```

Here's the situation. The 'arr' is an array converted from a string (and we get that string from user input). This code is checking if there's a zero in the 'arr', but it acts really weird. If the user inputs something like '123q', this message will be printed, even though there's no zero. Of course, if the input is '1230', it works just fine. I couldn't find any information about that, but i've spent a fairly good amount of time researching.

There's more to that.
Another piece of code, but closely related to my question.

```
  if string.match(/\D/)
    puts "Please, try again. You cannot use non-numerical characters!"
  end
```

In this case, if user input is '1230', this message will still be printed.

The question is: What's really going on there and how do i fix it? I need this code to check only for zero.

Ruby .include? method seems to think that 0 represents also all non-numerical characters and doesn't really represent itself. Is 0 non-numerical? How do i make it a number again so my 'if' would work the way i expect it to?

P.S. I'm using repl.it (current Ruby version 2.3.1p112) to run the code and there was no monkey-patching or anything like that.

Comment: How are you converting your user input into an array?

Comment: arr = gets.chomp.split("").map { |el| el.to_i }

Comment: When you convert a letter-only string such as `'q'` to an integer you get `0`. [See docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-to_i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
if '123q'.chars.include?('0')
  puts "Please, try again. You cannot use zero!"
end
```

Or

```
if '1230'.chars.map(&:to_i).include?(0)
  puts "Please, try again. You cannot use zero!"
end
```

**Update**

```
"rew212340weq232".chars.map {|x| x[/\d+/]}.compact.map(&:to_i)
#=> [2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: The second one is the thing i'm already using. Guess i should have mentioned that, sorry. Still, it doesn't work the way it's supposed to.

Comment: as mentioned in comments, `'q'.to_i` is resulting in `0`.

Comment: don't convert it into int, check for `'0'` instead. check updated answer

Comment: Unfortunatelly, i'm gonna have to find a way around that, cos i really need to convert them into int. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Gorgeous! Thank you so much. That's what i needed.

Comment: [`'1230'.split == ['1230']`](https://repl.it/INsZ). The first two examples do not work.

Comment: @axiac thanx! Too much excitement leads to errors..update/last answer was correct though. But `chars` is more elegant than `split` in this case.. (y)

Answer (score 2):

Your input probably isn't `'1230'` but `"1230\n"`, and `/\D/` matches `"\n"`.

You could use [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) to remove the trailing newline, and write a single regex to check if there are only digits but no `0`:

```
input.chomp =~ /\A[1-9]+\z/
```

Comment: Okay, thank you. I already use `chomp`, and it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't convert `string` to `integer`, it always result in 0**

**With 0:**

```
arr = "asds sad deff 0".chomp.split("")

 if (arr.include?(0) || arr.include?('0'))
    puts "Please, try again. You cannot use zero!"
  end

 result===>  Please, try again. You cannot use zero!
```

**Without 0:**

```
arr2 = "asds sad deff".chomp.split("")

 if (arr2.include?(0) || arr2.include?('0'))
    puts "Please, try again. You cannot use zero!"
  end

 result===>  nil
```

You can test for **`'0' or 0`** in the array and print the statement

Comment: I took his code and converted a sentence to an array

Comment: That can be done even without map..just for him to make sure he doesnot use `to_i` to the mapped value

Comment: explained in the above comment, to be more clearer for the questioner.

Comment: If you see one of the comments form the questionser, he used map to convert `string` to `integer.`. I removed the integer conversion from the map so that he can see what I changed. Anyway, if that does not make sense I will change it. Thank you. :)

Comment: That's just great. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to help you.. you ca upvote if you find it useful.. :)

Comment: I sure did.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, the issue is that `String#to_i` returns `0` for non-numeric values.

A simpler way to solve this is not to split the user input into an array at all, and simply to use regular expressions, as you did in your second code example:

```
loop do
  puts(defined?(user_input) ? 'Please enter a value:' : 'No zeroes allowed! Please try again:')
  user_input = gets.chomp
  break unless user_input.match(/0/)
end
```

Also, http://rubular.com is a great site for testing regular expressions. `'1234'` does *not* match `/\D/`, so there's probably something wrong with your implementation.